# check all radio button checked and then move to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want validate to check whether all radio buttons are checked and move to next division. There are five radio button groups. When I clicked submit button validate that five radio button groups to check whether clicked or not

HTML FILE:

```
<div class="RatContent animated slideInRight" id="question1">  

    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1 ;">
       <div class="col col-60">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <h5>How cleanlines is in office?</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col"><div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="good" id="good" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="good">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="ok" id="ok" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="ok">
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="bad" id="bad" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="bad">
             <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div></div>
   </div>

   <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1 ;">
       <div class="col col-60">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
              <h5>How cleanlines is in office?</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col"><div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion1" value="4" id="good1" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="good1">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion1" value="5" id="ok1" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="ok1">
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion1" value="6" id="bad1" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="bad1">
             <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1 ;">
       <div class="col col-60">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
              <h5>How cleanlines is in office?</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col"><div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion2" value="7" id="good2" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="good2">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion2" value="8" id="ok2" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="ok2">
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion2" value="9" id="bad2" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="bad2">
             <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1 ;">
       <div class="col col-60">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
              <h5>How cleanlines is in office?</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col"><div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion3" value="7" id="good3" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="good3">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion3" value="8" id="ok3" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="ok3">
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion3" value="9" id="bad3" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="bad3">
             <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1 ;">
       <div class="col col-60">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col">
              <h5>How cleanlines is in office?</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col"><div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion4" value="7" id="good4" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="good4">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion4" value="8" id="ok4" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="ok4">
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" name="emotion4" value="9" id="bad4" class="input-hidden" required />
            <label for="bad4">
             <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col next">
        <button type="submit" class="right">
          <i  style="color:black;" ng-click="openCity(event, 'question2' , 'question1')" class="ionicons ion-arrow-right-c"></i>
        </button> 
      </div>
   </div>

 <!-- End content-->
   </div>
```

JS FILE:

```
$scope.openCity = function(evt, cityName , Currentdiv) {
    var i, x;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("RatContent");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    var flag=0;
    $("#"+Currentdiv).find("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
        if($("input[type='radio']").is(':checked') == true ){
            flag=1;
            return false;
        }
    });

    alert(flag);

    if(flag==0){
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
      alert("sfsdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: `$("#"+Currentdiv).find("input[type='radio']:not(:checked)").length`?

Comment: Shouldn't this `if($("input[type='radio']").is(':checked') == true )` be `if($(this).is(':checked') == true )`

Comment: first comment code is  not working showing error on that line

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you had in mind but check it out: http://codepen.io/Knollo/pen/EgXLaW

For the sake of simplicity I've modified your DOM somewhat.

HTML

```
<div class="question">
  <p class="question__title">How cleanlines is in office?</p>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="good" id="good" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="good">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">good</i>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="ok" id="ok" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="ok">
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o">ok</i>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="bad" id="bad" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="bad">
             <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down">bad</i>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <p class="question__title">How cleanlines is in office?</p>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion1" value="4" id="good1" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="good1">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">good</i>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion1" value="5" id="ok1" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="ok1">
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o">okay</i>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion1" value="6" id="bad1" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="bad1">
             <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down">bad</i>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <p class="question__title">How cleanlines is in office?</p>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion2" value="7" id="good2" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="good2">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">good</i>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion2" value="8" id="ok2" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="ok2">
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o">okay</i>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion2" value="9" id="bad2" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="bad2">
             <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down">bad</i>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="question">
  <p class="question__title">How cleanlines is in office?</p>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion3" value="7" id="good3" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="good3">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">good</i>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion3" value="8" id="ok3" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="ok3">
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o">okay</i>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion3" value="9" id="bad3" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="bad3">
             <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down">bad</i>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="question">
  <p class="question__title">How cleanlines is in office?</p>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion4" value="7" id="good4" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="good4">
              <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">good</i>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion4" value="8" id="ok4" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="ok4">
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o">okay</i>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="question__answer">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion4" value="9" id="bad4" class="input-hidden" required />
    <label for="bad4">
             <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down">bad</i>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="validateGroups()">submit</button>
```

CSS (scss)

```
.question {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  &__title {
    font-weigth: bold;
    color: red;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
  }
}
```

Javascript

```
function validateGroups() {
  $questions = $('.question');

  $answeredQuestions = $questions.filter(checkForValidAnswer);

  if ($answeredQuestions.length != $questions.length) {
    alert('not all questions have been answered, yet.');
  } else {
    alert('all questions answered. proceeding...');
  }
}

function checkForValidAnswer($index, question) {
  // get all answers
  $answers = $(question).find('.question__answer');
  // try to find a checked answer
  $selectedAnswer = $answers.find('input:checked');

  // return false if no checked answer was found
  if ($selectedAnswer.length < 1)
    return false;
  // true, otherwise
  return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you i want to store all checked value from the 15 radio groups in array and console the array

Comment: but when i clicked last submit button it takes last 5 radio buttons only ...thats wrong  please give me an answer

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say. 15 radio groups? Maybe you mean the 15 radio buttons? Please fork my pen at codepen, make your changes and post the link here to help illustrate your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular js library but not using ng-repeat directive. Create an array which is have radio structure example:

```
$scope.myArray = [
  {
    "header" : "First",
    "radios" : [
        {
          "checked" : true,
          "icon" : "fa-smile",
          "id": "good"
        },
        {
          "checked" : true,
          "icon" : "fa-smile",
          "id": "good"
        }

      ]
  },
  {
    "header" : "Second",
    "radios" : [
        {
          "checked" : true,
          "icon" : "fa-smile",
          "id": "good"
        },
        {
          "checked" : true,
          "icon" : "fa-smile",
          "id": "good"
        }

      ]
  }
]
```

In your html create rows and radios with ng-repeat :

```
<div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1 ;" ng-repeat="data in myArray">
    <div class="col col-60">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h5>{{data.header}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" ng-repeat="myRadio in data.radios">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="radio" name="emotion" ng.model="myRadio" id="myRadio.id" class="input-hidden" required />
                <label for="myRadio.id">
                    <i class="fa {{myRadio.icon}}"></i>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```